# How to fix two different components in ReactJS while navigation and I am able to fix one but the other page is rendering both the fixed components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, navigation, react-router, react-dom

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/about" component={() => (<AboutScreen/>)}/>
  <Route exact path="/settings/reset_password" component={(props) => (<ResetPasswordScreen {...props}/>)}/>
    <div>
      <TopTab/>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/:community/post/:post" component={(props) => (<PostScreen {...props}/>)}/>
        <Route exact path="/:community/narrator/:link" component={(props) => (<PostScreen {...props}/>)}/>
        <div>
          <ExploreDiscussions/>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/discussions" component={() => (<DiscussionsScreen/>)}/>
            <Route exact path="/discussions/past" component={() => (<PastDiscussions/>)}/>
          </Switch>
        </div>
        <div>
          <ProfileData/>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/profile/:user" component={(props) => (<ProfileScreen {...props}/>)}/>
            <Route exact path="/profile/:user/followers" component={(props) => (<ProfileScreen {...props}/>)}/>
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Switch>
    </div>
  </Switch>
```

So, in the above code, I have fixed the TopTab(Navigation bar) for the pages. Now, I also fixed the ExploreDiscussions tab for all the discussions route. I want to fix the ProfileData for all the profile tabs but on the profile page, I am getting the ExploreDiscussions fixed component as well which I do not want on the profile routes.
How to fix this?

Comment: All children of a `<Switch>` should be `<Route>` or `<Redirect> `elements

Comment: @codekaizer So how to fix the Navbars and other elements for certain Routes

Comment: Split it to 3 different components with `Switch` inside.

Comment: Splitting into 3 different components not working.